# How does one use qsort to sort a char containing pathnames/files based on their bytes?

Tags: directory, sorting, c

I basically wrote a code in which I take two command line arguments one being the type of file that I want to search in my directory and they other being the amount I want(which is not implemented yet, but I can fix that) 
The code is like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define sizeFileName 500
#define filesMax 5000

int cmpfunc( const void *a, const void *b) {
  return *(char*)a + *(char*)b;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv) {
  FILE * fp = popen( "find . -type f", "r");
  char * type = argv[1];
  char * extension = ".";

  char* tExtension;
  tExtension = malloc(strlen(type)+1+4);
  strcpy(tExtension, extension);
  strcat(tExtension, type);
  // printf("%s\n",tExtension);

  int amount = atoi(argv[2]);
  //printf("%d\n",amount);

  char buff[sizeFileName];
  int nFiles = 0;
  char * files[filesMax];
  while(fgets(buff,sizeFileName,fp)) {
    int leng = strlen(buff) - 1;
    if (strncmp(buff + leng - 4, tExtension, 4) == 0){
      files[nFiles] = strndup(buff,leng);
      //printf("\t%s\n", files[nFiles]);
      nFiles ++;
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  printf("Found %d files\n", nFiles);

  long long totalBytes = 0;
  struct stat st;

  // sorting based on byte size from greatest to least
  qsort(files, (size_t) strlen(files), (size_t) sizeof(char), cmpfunc);

  for(int i = 0;i< nFiles; i ++) {
    if(0!= stat(files[i],&st)){
      perror("stat failed:");
      exit(-1);
    }
    totalBytes += st.st_size;
    printf("%s : %ld\n",files[i],st.st_size);
  }
  printf("Total size: %lld\n", totalBytes);
  // clean up
  for(int i = 0; i < nFiles ; i ++ ) {
    free(files[i]);
 }
  return 0;
}
```

So far I have every section set up properly, upon running the code say `$./find ini 5,` it would print out all the `ini files` followed by their byte size(it's currently ignore the 5). However, for the `qsort()`, I'm not exactly sure how I would sort the contents of `char * files` as while it holds the pathnames, I had to use `stat` to get the byte sizes, how would I print out a sorted version of my print statements featuring the first statement being the most bytes and finishes at the least bytes?

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose your input is valid, your question could be simplified with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define filesMax 5000

int cmpfunc(const void const *a, const void *b) { return *(char *)a + *(char *)b; }

int main(void) {
  int nFiles = 4;
  char *files[filesMax] = {"amazing", "hello", "this is a file", "I'm a bad file"};
  qsort(files, strlen(files), sizeof(char), cmpfunc);

  for (int i = 0; i < nFiles;; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", files[i]);
  }
}
```

If you compile with warning that give you:

```
source_file.c:11:23: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *[5000]' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  qsort(files, strlen(files), sizeof(char), cmpfunc);
                      ^~~~~
```

`qsort()` expect the size of your array (or in your case a subsize) and it's also expect the size of one element of your array. In both you wrongly give it to it. Also, your compare function doesn't compare anything, you are currently adding the first bytes of both pointer of char, that doesn't make a lot of sense.

To fix your code you must write:

```
qsort(files, nFiles, sizeof *files, &cmpfunc);
```

and also fix your compare function:

```
int cmpfunc_aux(char * const *a, char * const *b) { return strcmp(*a, *b); }

int cmpfunc(void const *a, void const *b) { return cmpfunc_aux(a, b); }
```

also size should be of type `size_t`:

```
size_t nFiles = 0;
```

Don't forget that all informations about how to use a function are write in their [doc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort).

---

> how would I print out a sorted version of my print statements featuring the first statement being the most bytes and finishes at the least bytes?

Your code don't show any clue that your are trying to do that, you are currently storing name file and only that. How do you expect sort your file with an information you didn't acquired ?

However, that simple create a struct that contain both file name and size, acquire information needed to sort it and sort it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct file {
  off_t size;
  char *name;
};

int cmpfunc_aux(struct file const *a, struct file const *b) {
  if (a->size > b->size) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a->size < b->size) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

int cmpfunc(void const *a, void const *b) { return cmpfunc_aux(a, b); }

#define filesMax 5000

int main(void) {
  size_t nFiles = 4;
  struct file files[filesMax] = {{42, "amazing"},
                                 {21, "hello"},
                                 {168, "this is a file"},
                                 {84, "I'm a bad file"}};
  qsort(files, nFiles, sizeof *files, &cmpfunc);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nFiles; i++) {
    printf("%s, %" PRId64 "\n", files[i].name, (intmax_t)files[i].size);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but so basically the stat st is where I'm getting my byte sizes from, if you attempt to run my code on a directory it would print out all the files of the given choice followed by their byte size.

Comment: @LiWang Are you asking me how to get the size of a file ? Or you just describe what your code is doing ?

Comment: My code can already print out a byte size if you were to run it, I'm been trying to figure out how I could sort it. The say if I run my code as /scan ini 5 I would get the output as: https://prnt.sc/l4k1rr

Answer (score 0):

The function `cmpfunc()` provided adds the first character of each string, and that's not a proper comparison function (it should give a opposite sign value when you switch the parameters, e.g. if `"a"` and `"b"` are the strings to compare, it adds the first two characters of both strings, giving `97+98 == 195`, which is positive on `unsigned char`s, then calling with `"b"` and `"a"` should give a negative number (and it again gives you `98 + 97 == 195`), more on, it always gives the same result ---even with `signed char`s--- so it cannot be used as a sorting comparator)

As you are comparing strings, why not to use the standard library function `strcmp(3)` which is a valid comparison function?  It gives a negative number if first string is less lexicographically than the second, `0` if both are equal, and positive if first is greater lexicographically than the second.

if your function has to check (and sort) by the lenght of the filenames, then you can define it as:

```
int cmpfunc(char *a, char *b) /* yes, you can define parameters as char * */
{
    return strlen(a) - strlen(b);
}
```

or, first based on file length, then lexicographically:

```
int cmpfunc(char *a, char *b)
{
    int la = strlen(a), lb = strlen(b);
    if (la != lb) return la - lb;
    /* la == lb, so we must check lexicographycally */
    return strcmp(a, b);
}
```

Now, to continue helping you, I need to know why do you need to sort anything, as you say that you want to search a directory for a file, where does the sorting take place in the problem?